# MySQL group by day and name

Tags: mysql

I need a MYSQL query where the date and the name are grouped.

I use following query, but it is not effective:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT NAME , COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE WHERE DATE between '2017-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DAY(DATE), NAME
) AS T
GROUP BY T.NAME;
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Here I have an example of how it should look:

```
original table          
+--------+------------+ 
| Name   | Date       |  
+--------+------------+ 
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-01 | 
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-02 | 
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-01 | 
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-03 | 
| NAME_3 | 2017-02-04 | 
| NAME_3 | 2017-02-04 | 
| NAME_3 | 2017-02-04 | 
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-02 | 
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-03 |             
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-04 |             
+--------+------------+ 

first Group by DAY(DATE)        
+--------+------------+--------+
| Name   | Date       | Count  | 
+--------+------------+--------+
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-01 | 1      |
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-02 | 1      |
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-03 | 1      |
| NAME_3 | 2017-02-04 | 3      |
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-02 | 1      |        
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-03 | 1      |        
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-04 | 1      |        
+--------+------------+--------+

second: group by NAME and this is a final output        
+--------+------------+--------+
| Name   | Date       | Count  |
+--------+------------+--------+
| NAME_1 | 2017-02-01 | 3      |
| NAME_3 | 2017-02-04 | 3      |
| NAME_2 | 2017-02-02 | 3      |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: not sure about name_3 having count of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `count(distinct ...)` would work here e.g.

```
  SELECT
        NAME
      , COUNT(distinct DAY(DATE)) AS count
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE DATE >= '2017-02-01' AND DATE < '2017-03-01'
  GROUP BY
        NAME
```

Please don't do this:

```
WHERE DATE between '2017-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-28 23:59:59'
```

It is far easier to use this instead:

```
  WHERE DATE >= '2017-02-01' AND DATE < '2017-03-01'
```

- you don't have to calculate the "last day" of the month, always use the first day of next month (which is always one :) instead.
- using `>=` and `<` is accurate for every type of date/time data regardles of how precisely it is stored.